# shape not as expected for my array

Tags: numpy, ipython, jupyter-notebook, mnist

Hello consider following code:

```
# load the mnist training data CSV file into a list
training_data_file = open("Training_Set/mnist_train_100.csv", 'r')
training_data_list = training_data_file.readlines()
training_data_file.close()

caches_x = []
caches_y = []
for record in training_data_list:
    all_values = record.split(',')
    x_inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
    y_inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[0]))

    cache_x = (x_inputs)
    caches_x.append(cache_x)

    cache_y = (y_inputs)
    caches_y.append(cache_y)



train_x = np.array(caches_x).T

print("shape of train_x = " + str(train_x.shape))
print("train_x =" + str(train_x))

train_y = np.array(caches_y).T

print("shape of train_y = " + str(train_y.shape))
print("train_y =" + str(train_y))
```

When I Print the shape of train_x I have (784,103), is what I expect.

When I print the shape of train_y I have (103,)

What do I do wrong? Also for train_y I expect (or want to have) as shape (1,103)
Can somebody help me out? tnx.

Comment: `cashe_y` is a list of numbers.  `np.array([1,2,3,4])` produces a 1d array.  If you don't understand that, then you need to do some basic numpy reading.  In that reading you'll also learn about reshaping arrays and adding dimensions.

Comment: try to reshape y_inputs : y_inputs.reshape(1,-1) this will do the job. 
Note : If you have x.shape = 784,103 it's usually to say you have 784 different inputs to train on w.r.t 103 features. So you expect y to be (784,1) one output for each input.
In the case of classification as in the mnist case, y.shape is [number_of_inputs, number_of_class]